# Can I load image for dsl.ContainerOp from a local docker save file

Tags: docker-image, kubeflow-pipelines

now I'm using dockerhub to store my docker image and load it to kubeflow like that:
`

```
 def my_pipeline():
        doing = dsl.ContainerOp(
        name='training',
          image='<my-user>/<my-docker-image>',
          command=['hello.py'],
          output_artifact_paths= {}
          )
```

`

but I want to load base image for  dsl.ContainerOp locally from a docker image save file, how can I do this?

Thank for any help!